# Dúvida com consulta usando LINQ e NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Preciso de ajuda em uma query que deve buscar:

> PK_PARENT, NOME_PAI, {NOME_FILHO1, NOME_FILHO2, ..., NOME_FILHO*}

Para a pesquisa eu já tentei fazer a pesquisa de algumas formas como:

```
var listaPai = (from parent in session.Query<Parent>() select parent).ToList();

var dto = listaPai.Select(parent => new DTOListaPai
{
    Codigo = parent.Codigo,
    NomePai = parent.Nome,
    // aqui eu faço uma consulta e já monto uma string com o formato  
    // desejado
    NomesFilho = string.Join(",", session.Query<Child>()
        .Where<Child>(
            child => child.Parent.Codigo == parent.Codigo)
        .ToList())
```

> ERRO: Quando a consulta faz a validação de 
>   `Where<Child>(child => child.Parent.Codigo == parent.Codigo)` o método `GetHashCode()` da classe Child é invocado e no momento em que tenta fazer a conversão `Convert.ToInt32(this.Parent.Codigo)` estoura uma exceção de instância de objeto nulo. Creio que estou errando nesse ponto, ou talvez em alguma anotação que falta no mapeamentos.

Os detalhes sobre a implementação no banco de dados estão comentados no código abaixo.

---

Classes exemplo:

```
public class Parent {
    //pk_parent == Codigo
    public virtual long Codigo { get; set; }
    public virtual string NomePai { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Child> Childs { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(object obj1)
    {
        var obj2 = obj1 as Parent;

        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj2)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj2)) return true;

        return this.Codigo == obj2.Codigo;
    }

    public int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(this.Codigo);
    }        
}

public class Child {
    // pk_child == NomeFilho && Parent.Codigo
    public virtual string NomeFilho { get; set; }
    // fk_parent == Parent.Codigo
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj1)
    {
        var obj2 = obj1 as Child;

        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj2)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj2)) return true;

        return this.NomeFilho == obj2.NomeFilho &&
               this.Parent.Codigo == obj2.Parent.Codigo;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(this.Parent.Codigo) + NomeFilho.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

- pk_child é composta pela fk_parent + nomeFilho

---

Mapeamentos:

```
public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    Table("tb_parent");
    Id(parent => parent.Codigo)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Column("pk_parent")
            .GeneratedBy.Sequence("tb_parent_pk_parent_seq");
    Map(parent => parent.Nome).Column("nome_pai")
            .Not.Nullable();
    HasMany(parent => parent.Childs)
            .KeyColumn("fk_parent")
            .Cascade.All()
            .AsBag();
}

public class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
{
    Table("tb_child");
    CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(child => child.Parent.Codigo, "fk_parent")
            .KeyProperty(child=> child.Nome, "nome_filho");

    References(child => child.Parent, "fk_parent");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, eu não uso Fluent, apenas o NHibernate puro com Mapping-by-code. O que faço nesse caso é referenciar tudo certinho, criando corretamente as "bags" para que eu possa fazer a iteração e retornar todos os registros filhos desta classe.

**Ex.:**

```
public partial class Pessoa
{
    public virtual long IdPessoa { get; set; } // Nossa PK

    // ...Suas propriedades aqui etc, só pra exemplificar

    // Você precisa criar a classe Apelido
    public virtual IEnumerable<Apelido> ApelidoBag { get; set; }
}
```

Minha classe de mapeamento fica assim (lembre que além do mapeamento abaixo, você também precisa criar a classe de mapeamento para a classe Apelido):

```
public partial class PessoaMap : ClassMapping<Pessoa>
{
    Schema("SEU_ESQUEMA");
    Lazy(true);

    // Nossa PK que é alimentada por uma sequence de exemplo (no Oracle)
    Id(x => x.IdPessoa, map =>
    {
        map.Column("ID_PESSOA");
        map.Generator(Generators.Sequence, g => g.Params(new
        {
            sequence = "SQ_EXEMPLO"
        }));
    });

    // ...Todos os itens do mapeamento do BD aqui etc, só pra exemplificar.

    Bag(x => x.ApelidoBag, colmap =>
    {
        colmap.Key(x => x.Column("ID_PESSOA"));
        colmap.Inverse(true);
    },
    map => { map.OneToMany(); });
}
```

Desta forma eu posso fazer o *SELECT* usando o *LINQ* (lembre de referenciar *System.Linq* e *NHibernate.Linq*) apenas buscando a pessoa (pelo ID, por exemplo) e quando eu precisar faço um foreach na lista (bag) porque automaticamente ele vai trazer todos os registros desta "pessoa".

**Ex.:**

```
return suaSessao
    .Query<Pessoa>
    .Where(x => x.IdPessoa == 12345)
    .SingleOrDefault()
;
```

Por conta do **Lazy(true);** do Nhibernate, você pode trazer a qualquer momento os registros filhos somente chamando a propriedade **ApelidosBag** e fazendo a devida iteração nela.

**Ex.:**

```
foreach (Apelido item in seuObjPessoa.ApelidosBag)
{
    // Faça o que tiver que fazer aqui
}
```